# Unable to do post request

Tags: .net, post, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I´m able to do a GET-request successfully. However when i´m trying to do a Post-request from Postman, it returns a "Bad Request"-message.

[image]

I have tried with [FromBody] and without, but same problem occurs.

Below is my Postman request.

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot , it should work . You could refer to [this blog](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request) which maybe help you to check  and fix the error . If you need the community review and debug code ,please show a complete demo and the code of request that can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should return something in `ExternalLogin`. Return `ActionResult` and not `IActionResult`.

Comment: @Manusb I tried returning ActionResult. Unfortunately same problem.